# Laravel listing and summing scores in multiple loops in the same table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to turn the data in a single table with a nested loop and first list the countries and then collect the points of each service to group the cities and services of the cities.

**My Table : Services**

```
CREATE TABLE `Service` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `services` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `point` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `country`, `city`, `services`, `point`, `status`) VALUES
('8', 'ABD', 'TEXAS', 'Food', '20', 'active'),
('9', 'ABD', 'TEXAS', 'Food', '40', 'active'),
('10', 'ABD', 'MONTANA', 'Hotel', '10', 'active'),
('11', 'ABD', 'MONTANA', 'Food', '70', 'active'),
('12', 'ABD', 'MONTANA', 'Hotel', '20', 'active'),
('13', 'ABD', 'TEXAS', 'Shopping', '80', 'active'),
('14', 'ITALY', 'ROMA', 'Shopping', '20', 'active'),
('15', 'ITALY', 'ROMA', 'Hotel', '90', 'active'),
('16', 'ITALY', 'LAZIO', 'Shopping', '80', 'active'),
('17', 'TURKEY', 'ANTALYA', 'Hotel', '10', 'active'),
('18', 'TURKEY', 'ISTANBUL', 'Shopping', '100', 'active'),
('19', 'TURKEY', 'ISTANBUL', 'Hotel', '50', 'active'),
('20', 'TURKEY', 'ISTANBUL', 'Hotel', '90', 'active');
```

[image]

**The result I want to get**
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group country and city using collection

```
$service= \App\Models\Service::get()->groupBy(['country','city']);
```

**Updated**

```
$service= \App\Models\Service::get()->groupBy(['country','city','services'])->map(function ($city) {

     return $city->map(function ($services) {

          return $services->map(function ($service) {

                return $service->sum('point');

            });

        });
       
    });
```

**Updated**

```
$service= \App\Models\Service::get()->groupBy(['country','city','services'])->map(function ($city) {
    
         return $city->map(function ($services) {
    
              return $services->map(function ($service) {

                    return ['serviceName'=>$service->first()->services,'sum'=>$service->sum('point'),"count"=>$service->count()];

                });

            });
           
        });
```

Comment: I'm dividing into groups in the same way, but I'm not getting the point totals for each point. egg: italy->roma->shooping: 110.  Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: In this query, italy rome should come as 110, but it only returns the score of the first record 20 points. egg: [link]https://ibb.co/31wgxGY

Comment: @YunusKocabay its grouping country->city->services->sum of point

Comment: @YunusKocabay can you give sql file with data  or else difficult guess

Comment: John  I added it to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234623/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-yunus-kocabay).

Comment: I want to get the count(*) of lines next to point, how do I do that?

Comment: @YunusKocabay kindly create new question for that

Comment: When I try to open a new message "You have reached your question limit"

Comment: @YunusKocabay really not sure about it but may be you have asked many question in one day or somethink else

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273741/stack-overflow-you-have-reached-your-question-limit

Comment: Loba :( I'm so sorry they won't let me ask questions

Comment: @YunusKocabay .base idea already answered so first try yourself .if i get time i wll check

Comment: one thing you can do is  return ['serviceName'=>$service->first()->services,'sum'=>$service->sum('point'),"count"=>$service->count()];

Comment: I give you my endless thanks. You are a wonderful human being! Thank you, good person :)